# How to implement Log out Functionality in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

What is the best way to implement the logout functionality in react native in my case when i click the logout button it works fine but next time when i again login and click it it does not work.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import {url} from '../globals';
import Toast from 'react-native-simple-toast';

class Logout extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onLogOutPressed = this.onLogOutPressed.bind(this);
  }
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };
  componentWillMount() {
    this.onLogOutPressed();
    this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this.onLogOutPressed);
  }
  async onLogOutPressed() {
    try {
      let response = await fetch(url + '/auth/Logout', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });
      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        console.log('Request Status ', response.status);
        let res = await response.json();
        console.log('Logout response:', res);
        Toast.showWithGravity(res, Toast.LONG, Toast.CENTER);
        await AsyncStorage.clear();
        this.props.navigation.navigate('login');
      } else {
        throw 'Enable to parse';
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error ' + error);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
export default Logout;
```

And this is the stack navigator and drawer navigation when i click on the logout button for the first time it work fine but second time it move to me last visited page

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

import Login from './src/pages/Login';
import Companies from './src/admin/Companies';
import LicensesTable from './src/admin/VerifyLicenses';
import EditLicense from './src/admin/EditLicense';
import ActionEdit from './src/admin/EditLicenseDetails';
import PricingPlan from './src/admin/PricingPlan';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createDrawerNavigator, DrawerItems} from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import {createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import AdmDash from './src/admin/AdminDashboard';
import Users from './src/admin/Users';
import Logout from './src/pages/Logout';

global.currentScreenIndex = 0;
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.disableYellowBox = true;
    return  <Draw />;
  }
}

const CompaniesStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    CompaniesNavigator: {screen: Companies},
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      return {
        title: 'Companies',
        headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#1D60D2'},
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerLeft: (
          <Icon
            style={{paddingLeft: 10, color: 'white'}}
            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
            name="md-menu"
            size={30}
          />
        ),
      };
    },
  },
);


const PricingStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    PricingNavigator: {screen: PricingPlan},
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      return {
        title: 'Pricing Plan',
        headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#1D60D2'},
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerLeft: (
          <Icon
            style={{paddingLeft: 10, color: 'white'}}
            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
            name="md-menu"
            size={30}
          />
        ),
      };
    },
  },
);



const UserStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    UserNavigator: Users,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      return {
        title: 'Users',
        headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#1D60D2'},
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerLeft: (
          <Icon
            style={{paddingLeft: 10, color: 'white'}}
            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
            name="md-menu"
            size={30}
          />
        ),
      };
    },
  },
);


const DashboardStackNavigatorAdmin = createStackNavigator(
  {
    DashboardNavigator: {screen: AdmDash},
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      return {
        title: 'Dashboard',
        headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#1D60D2'},
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerLeft: (
          <Icon
            style={{paddingLeft: 10, color: 'white'}}
            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
            name="md-menu"
            size={30}
          />
        ),
      };
    },
  },
);

const LicensesStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    LicensesNavigator: {screen: LicensesTable},
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      return {
        title: 'Verify Licenses',
        headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#1D60D2'},
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerLeft: (
          <Icon
            style={{paddingLeft: 10, color: 'white'}}
            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
            name="md-menu"
            size={30}
          />
        ),
      };
    },
  },
);

const LogoutStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  LogOutNAvigator: {
    screen: Logout,
  },
});

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  login: {screen: Login},
  EditLicense: {screen: EditLicense},
  ActionEdit: {screen: ActionEdit},
},
{
  initialRouteName: "login"
});



const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    login: {
      screen: AppNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: () => null,
      },
    },
    Home: {
      screen: DashboardStackNavigatorAdmin,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: () => 'Dashboard',
        drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <Icon name="md-home" style={{fontSize: 24, color: tintColor}} />
        ),
      },
    },

    Users: {
      screen: UserStackNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <Icon name="md-person" style={{fontSize: 24, color: tintColor}} />
        ),
      },
    },

    'Pricing Plan':{
      screen:PricingStackNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <Icon name="md-pricetag" style={{fontSize: 24, color: tintColor}} />
        ),
      },
    },

    Licenses: {
      screen: LicensesStackNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <Icon name="md-briefcase" style={{fontSize: 24, color: tintColor}} />
        ),
      },
    },

    Companies: {
      screen: CompaniesStackNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <Icon name="md-card" style={{fontSize: 24, color: tintColor}} />
        ),
      },
    },

    Logout: {
      screen: LogoutStackNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <Icon name="md-log-out" style={{fontSize: 24, color: tintColor}} />
        ),
      },
    },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View>
          <Image
            source={require('./src/Images/download.png')}
            style={styles.sideMenuProfileIcon}
          />
          <Text></Text>
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
          <DrawerItems {...props} />
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    ),
    drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width - 130,
  },
);

const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Dashboard: {screen: AppDrawerNavigator},
  Users: {screen: Users},
  Companies: {screen: Companies},
  Licenses: {screen: LicensesTable},
});

const Draw = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  IconS: {
    paddingLeft: 10,
  },
  HeaderStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#1D60D2',
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignContent: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  sideMenuContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: 20,
  },
  sideMenuProfileIcon: {
    resizeMode: 'center',
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    marginTop: 20,
    borderRadius: 75,
    alignContent: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Please share some code with what you have tried. This should be possible and I suspect some state variable is not being set or unset correctly.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @TeddySterne i edited my question and there it is

Comment: @RameezRahil What have you tried to fix the issue? Is it calling your method? Is the API not giving you a correct status code? Have you verified that the user has a session before and after they navigate to the Logout screen?

Comment: @TeddySterne no i cant fix the issue its calling the method and API and the API giving me the correct response. in 1st attempt it work fine but in 2nd time it does not send me to login screen

Comment: @RameezRahil So the second time when it doesn't work. Is the API request still made? Does it throw 'Enable to parse' error?

Comment: @TeddySterne In 2nd time API request still made but it doesn't redirect me to login page

Comment: @RameezRahil what is the status code you receive?

Comment: @TeddySterne 200

Comment: @RameezRahil I would suggest changing the `login` route in the `AppDrawerNavigator` to be something different. I think `react-navigation` gets a little confused when there are multiple screens/navigators with the same key name.

Comment: @TeddySterne ok would you suggest me any of your project that login and navigate to dashboard and after logout it put you again login page

Comment: @RameezRahil Sorry I don't have any publicly available apps I can share. Did my suggestion work for you? If you can share your repo with me I would be happy to take a look.

Comment: @TeddySterne so you have any privately availabile app ...???

Comment: @RameezRahil By definition private apps are not publicly available so no I do not. Are you able to share your code?

Comment: @TeddySterne this is my organization's project i can't able to share this code with you

Comment: @RameezRahil did changing the `login` route in the `AppDrawerNavigator` to something different fix the problem?

Comment: @TeddySterne No

Comment: @RameezRahil Without more information around debugging and without being able to look at your code it is difficult to assess where the problem is. I put together this demo to hopefully help you figure out what might be going wrong https://snack.expo.io/SJqtWayv8

Answer (score 0):

I realise logout in Drawer without conponent, simple overload onItemPress (Typescript example):

```
<DrawerItems
      {...props}
      items={props.items.filter((i: any) => i.key !== 'UserProfile')}
      getLabel={({route}: Scene) => {
        const title = props.descriptors[route.key].options.title;
        return (
          <Text
            style={
              route.key !== 'Logout'
                ? styles.labelStyle
                : styles.labelExitStyle
            }>
            {t(title)}
          </Text>
        );
      }}
      //labelStyle={styles.labelStyle}
      itemStyle={styles.itemStyle}
      iconContainerStyle={styles.iconOpacity}
      onItemPress={({route}) => {
        if (route.key === 'Logout') {
          Alert.alert(
            t('Logout'),
            t('Are you sure you want to logout?'),
            [
              {
                text: t('Ok'),
                onPress: async () => {
                  const result = await clearProfile();
                  if (result) {
                    navigate('Choose');
                  }
                },
              },
              {text: t('Cancel'), style: 'cancel'},
            ],
            {
              cancelable: false,
            },
          );
        } else {
          navigate(route.key);
        }
      }}
    />
```

It's your Darwer menu:

```
createDrawerNavigator(
        {
          ...
          Logout: {
            screen: Choose,
            navigationOptions: {
              title: 'Logout',
              drawerIcon: <Image source={iconRedExit} style={styles.icon} />,
            },
          },
        },
        {
          initialRouteName: 'Tests',
          contentComponent: CustomDrawer,
          drawerWidth: width,
        },
      ),
```

In your CustomDrawer render() you can use DrawerItems from my answer